# Python open cv2 ip web cam doesn't work its showing error

Tags: python, opencv

Python open cv2 ip web cam doesn't work its showing error....my ip is also correct but

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://192.168.4.18:8080/Image')

while True:

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imgshow("Capturing",frame)
    #print('Running..')

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    cv2.imgshow("Capturing",frame)
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'imgshow'
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**check this It's grametical mistakes**

cv2.imshow("capturing",frame)

Answer (score 0):

Change imgshow to imshow

I.e.,

```
cv2.imshow("capturing",frame)
```

Open cv2 have  function called as imshow which help us to show the frames.

For more info you should visit

[Cv2.imshow](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/deb/tutorial_display_image.html)